# Gatsby build error #95313, Audio is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, referenceerror

I think that an audio object is throwing a ReferenceError when building on Gatsby and I don't really know why. I've read it may be because of Node.JS, so I guess the way I'm creating the audio object is not the right one. The develop version works completely fine tho. This is the component where I created the audio object:

```
const Button = value => {
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);

  //Switch state
  const switchit = () => {setPlay(!play)}
  //Getting track info
  const track = value.value
  const trackName = track && track.name ? track.name : null;
  const trackPath = track && track.publicURL ? track.publicURL : null;
  //Making track playable
  const playAudio = new Audio(trackPath)
  
  const playSound = () => {
    if (play === false) {
      playAudio.play();
      switchit()
      setTimeout(() => {
        setPlay(false)
      }, playAudio.duration * 1000);
    } else {}
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <ButtonStyle onClick={playSound}>{trackName}</ButtonStyle>
    </>
  )
}

export default Button
```

And this is the error thrown when I try to build the project:

```
 ERROR 

Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-index-js",
  "path": "/",
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {}
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": [
    "3649515864",
    "3652344105",
    "63159454"
  ]
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.380s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

  WebpackError: ReferenceError: Audio is not defined

  - index.js:15 
    webpack:/facusounds/src/components/Button/index.js:15:21

  - index.js:22 
    [facusounds]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:22:1

  - index.js:25 
    [facusounds]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:25:1

  - index.js:31 
    [facusounds]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:31:1

  - index.js:30 
    [facusounds]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:30:4

  - index.js:41 
    [facusounds]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:41:1

  - static-entry.js:294 
    webpack:/facusounds/.cache/static-entry.js:294:22

  - dev-404-page.js:15 
    facusounds/.cache/dev-404-page.js:15:11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gatsby is trying to access the `Audio` object, which is only available client side. You'll need to add some conditional logic that checks for the availability of the global `window` object.

```js
const [playAudio] = useState(window !== 'undefined' ? new Audio(trackPath) : null)
```

If you need to update the `Audio` object when `trackPath` changes, you can use `useEffect` which only runs client side (so no need for window check):

```js
const [playAudio, setAudio] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  setAudio(new Audio(trackPath))
}, [trackPath])
```

Comment: It worked! I had to make a change tho. I looked through the Gatsby documentation and saw they use a typeof instead of useState and it led me to build it. This is the final code:   const playAudio = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? new Audio(trackPath) : null

Comment: @aZero Good catch!